# Problem in center an ActivityIndicatorView in a UIButton

Tags: ios, layout, uibutton, center, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to center a UIActivityIndicatorView in a UIButton programmatically using constraints but it's not working..
Note: It's centered if you rotate the device!

[image]

The code i'm using is

```
func animateButton(shouldLoad: Bool, with message: String) {
    
    
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = !shouldLoad
    
    // Should start loading
    if shouldLoad {

        self.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { 
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
            self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.midX - self.frame.height / 2, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.height, height: self.frame.height)
        }, completion: { (done) in
            if done {
                self.showLoading()
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    self.spinner.alpha = 1
                    self.layoutIfNeeded()
                })
            }
        })
        
    // Should end loading
    } else {
        
        self.setTitle(message, for: .normal)
        
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview == spinner {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { 
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            self.frame = self.originalFrame!
        })
        
    }
    
}

func showLoading() {
    if (spinner == nil) {
        spinner = createSpinner()
    }
    
    self.addSubview(spinner)
    centerActivityIndicatorInButton()
    spinner.startAnimating()
}

func hideLoading() {
    spinner.stopAnimating()
}

private func createSpinner() -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
    activityIndicator.color = UIColor.darkGray
    activityIndicator.alpha = 0
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    
    return activityIndicator
}

private func centerActivityIndicatorInButton() {
    spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: spinner, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(xCenterConstraint)
    
    let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: spinner, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
}
```

It works in case of calculating the center manually using this code.. But in case of rotation it's not working and it's not 100% accurate as we need to add 1point to width & height

```
let buttonHeight = self.bounds.size.height
let buttonWidth = self.bounds.size.width
spinner.center = CGPoint(x: buttonWidth/2, y: buttonHeight/2)
```

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Use the superview’s `bounds`, not its `frame`, when determining the placement of the subview/sublayer

Comment: Is this code in a `UIButton` subclass?

Comment: @paulw11 Yes.. I'm trying to subclass UIButton with these functionalities

Comment: And is the button itself placed using constraints or are you manipulating its frame?  I see you are animating the frame in `animateButton` - Generally you shouldn't mix frame manipulation and autolayout.  If you want to change the size of the button, add & remove or modify size constraints.

Comment: Yes.. It's originally placed using constraints.. But i need to manipulate it's size but changing the frame..

Thanks for bringing this general issue to me but i still need to make a general subclass which will be used anytime later.. and there's no other way except manipulating the button's frame!